# Laravel 5.1 + beanstalkd + centos6

Tags: redis, laravel-5.1, centos6, beanstalkd

Ive installed Beanstalkd on my server for my Laravel 5.1 application. But i think im overseeing something. I followed this steps: http://www.techtransit.org/install-beanstalk-centos-7-rhel-7-fedora-vps-server/

After it requested the beanstalk status and its running. Then i run my artisan queue:listen --queue="test" but my queue is not handled. What am i missing? On local it works fine with Homestead and testing the queue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must try

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=<queue_name>
```